# Client Side script not triggering server side

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a google script where values are inputed on a sidebar form and then with those values a script should be ran, but the function is not being called.

```
    <script>

  function submitForm() {
    console.log('Function called!');
    var company = document.getElementById("company").value;
    var companyOtherInput = document.getElementById("company-other-input").value;
    if (company === "Other") {
      company = companyOtherInput;
    }
    var role = document.getElementById("role").value;
    var position = document.getElementById("position").value;
    google.script.run.test();
    console.log(company);
    console.log(role);
    console.log(position);
    
  }
 </script>
```

then for testing pourposes I am running this script on server side

```
function  test() {
 Browser.msgBox('script running');
 console.log('called');
}
```

been at it with ChatGPT for hours but can't seem to get it to run the fuction

Comment: In your situation, where are your Google Apps Script and HTML put as the container-bound script? Google Spreadsheet? Google Form? Or, other? In your showing script, how is the function `submitForm()` run? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: From `submitForm` do you see all the `console.log()` messages?

Comment: The submitForm logs all post to the console. But none from the test() function.

Comment: The submitForm() runs when a sidebar form is submitted , this is in google sheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I think that when `submitForm()` at Javascript side is correctly run, `test()` at Google Apps Script side is run. But, you say `but the function is not being called.`. In this case, I think that it is required to correctly replicate your situation. So, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current situation? By the way, when you add `@` to the user name line `@username` in the reply, the user can notice your reply.